# How to debug html code for which css is being applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some demo examples which i downloaded from net, 
it uses some css and java scripts, code for one of the  is very simple and don't have any style specified.
 but when i open the html page in chrome and do view source, i see style elements like width and height.
There are many css being imported, how do i debug and reach to the code which is applying style on this div?
Any help much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the developer tool's in the browser to view the code in detail and even make a few CSS/HTML changes to see how this change would look in the browser.

In **Internet Explorer** you can press F12 to view the developer tools.

In **Chrome**, right click and "inspect element" and in **Mozilla**(My favourite) use the Firebug extension...

Answer (score 2):

The very simple answer here is to use **[FIREBUG](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)** a firefox addon.
If you are using chrome, do **right click** and **inspect element**.

This will help you to debug your html code exhaustively.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome, right click => inspection, select a property and the CSS file will be shown